# jQuery and extending built-in elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, extends, custom-element

I am just looking into [extending built-in elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) for the first time and have some basic questions.

Let's say I want to extend a `p` element, assign it a class, and make it `contenteditable`. Is the following correct and ready-to-use?

```
      customElements.define('p-edit', pedit, { extends: 'p' });

      class pedit extends HTMLParagraphElement {
        constructor() {
            
            super();
          
            this.classList.add("foo");
            this.setAttribute("contenteditable",true);
        
        }
    }
```

And would that `pedit` element be a valid jQuery `selector`? And would it be a match if the jQuery selector were `'p[contenteditable="true"]'` ?

Comment: Sure, setting the `contenteditable` attribute in the `constructor` is a fine way to do it. And yes, your selector would work. Though you should first define the `class` before calling `customElements.define`. Be aware that Customizing built-in elements are not supported in Safari.

Comment: This looks correct. Here is a working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XWzRoaY?editors=1111) -- Notice there is no jQuery loaded ;)

Comment: Thanks to you both.  If we have a `tabindex` attribute in the `pedit` custom element, how would the tabindex be passed to the constructor when instantiating the element in javascript :   `document.createElement('pedit', {is: "pedit"})`

Comment: About the jQuery selector, what about `$("p.foo")` ? Another [codepen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vYWmvjE?editors=1111)

Comment: About `tabIndex` attributes, I guess you will have to loop each elements to set them correctly.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette:  I thought codepen would automatically generate a version if I made an edit. I'm afraid I clobbered your example when testing whether it was possible to add the element using javascript instead of via markup.

Comment: No.. My examples are untouched. To save a modification you would have to fork it. It would then be saved under your account.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch *Customized Built-In Elements* and stick to *Autonomous Elements* `extends HTMLElement`.

Unless you want to rely on polyfills forever.

Apple has, since 2016, stated they never will implement *Customized Built-In Elements* in Safari.

source: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/509

[image]

Comment: "Autonomous custom elements are new HTML tags, defined entirely by the author. They have none of the semantics of existing HTML elements, so all behaviors need to be defined by the  author. "   ( https://www.webcomponents.org/specs#:~:text=Autonomous%20custom%20elements%20are%20new,HTML%20elements%20with%20custom%20functionality. )  Defining all behaviors is exactly what I *don't* want to do.  If Microsoft Edge can use Chromium why can't Apple Safari do so too?

Comment: Most likely for the same reason you use a Mac and I a PC, or reverse

Comment: And, there hardly is any difference between an extended ``<p>`` or a ``<my-p>`` extended from HTMLElement (which ``<p>`` is extended from also). HTMLElement is the main workhorse in HTML

Comment: I would want to extend `<my-p>` from `<p>` (not from HTMLElement) and wouldn't really change default behaviors, just set default properties and attributes. But that is not very easy, I've found, so I'm resorting to the Factory pattern.

Comment: ``align`` is the only property you get for free in ``HTMLParagraphElement`` over ``HTMLElement``. If that is not easy to recreate, you might be better off with React? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLParagraphElement OH, and ``align`` is deprecated...